# Not able to add a link in code igniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am a beginner to Wamp server. I am trying to design a website with project name as "helloall" in netbeans IDE.

In the views folder I have two files `layout1.php` and `layout2.php`.

I am trying to call `layout2.php` from `layout1.php` in the below style.

```
 <div id="logo"> <a href="layout2.php" title="layoutishere"><span>LAYOUT2</span></a> </div>
```

But I am facing the below error, for which I am not able to find the reason.
    The requested URL `/helloall/layout2.php` was not found on this server.

Do I need to change anything in the configuration? I am using all the default configurations.

Comment: If layout2 is in same folder in which layout1 is, then no error should be there,whatever the configuration is.

Answer (score 3):

as per Codeigniter standard you have to follow the MVC pattern so:

Model -> Controller ->view

now, assuming you want to visualize `layout2.php` view you have 2 chances:

1 - load view directly where you need `$this->load->view('layout2');`

2 - create url function ad hoc kind of `www.site.com/layout/layout1` and `www.site.com/layout/layout2`:

controller `layout.php`

```
    class Layout extends CI_Controller {

        function layout1(){
            $this->load->view('layout1');
    }
        function layout2(){
            $this->load->view('layout2');
    }
}
```

i really suggest you to look at How To Create a Controller in [Codeigniter Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)